# Pandas Dataframe display total

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is an example dataset found from google search close to my datasets in my environment

[image]

I'm trying to get output like this

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Product':['Box','Bottles','Pen','Markers','Bottles','Pen','Markers','Bottles','Box','Markers','Markers','Pen'],
        'State':['Alaska','California','Texas','North Carolina','California','Texas','Alaska','Texas','North Carolina','Alaska','California','Texas'],
        'Sales':[14,24,31,12,13,7,9,31,18,16,18,14]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Product','State','Sales'])
df1=df.sort_values('State')
#df1['Total']=df1.groupby('State').count()   
df1['line']=df1.groupby('State').cumcount()+1
print(df1.to_string(index=False))
```

```
 Commented out line throws this error 
 ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
 
Tried with size() it gives NaN for all rows
```

Hope someone points me to right direction
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for 'Total':

```
df1['Total']=df1.groupby('State')['Product'].transform(lambda x: x.count())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values("State")

grp = df.groupby("State")
df["Total"] = grp["State"].transform("size")
df["line"] = grp.cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: It's not working for some reason.Total give NaN for all rows

Comment: Sorry, some bad copy & paste. Fixed